# como puedo hacer un loop que me divida un número por partes iguales dependiendo de otro y mostrarlo

Tags: php, fpdf

para ser más exactos estaba trabajando en hacer unos tickets y estoy un poco atascado en una parte del ticket que muestra "pieza 1 de 2" y esta es la parte que se me complica ya que dependiendo de un número lo llamare "cajas" es la cantidad donde dice "2", lo primero que hago es una variable con cantidad solicitada y esta la divido con la de "cajas" y así pues sería sacando el segundo número pero el problema es como le hago para mostrar el donde va el "1" la cantidad equitativa de tickets ?, tengo un loop  y pues este funciona de manera similar pero al ser número impares a veces la cantidad no se reparte equitativamente ya que funciona por "hoja" por así decirlo ya que por pagina lo tengo que gracias al for cambia cada pagina dependiendo de la cantidad de cajas pero no lo hace por ticket ese es el problema alguna idea?.

por ejemplo si son 100 tickets y 4 cajas pues quiero 25 tickets que digan pieza 1 de 4 y así sucesivamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí debajo adjunto el código, realmente me serviría cualquier ejemplo simple, no es necesario que me resuelvan todo el código solo lo pongo aquí debajo porque quizás es algo complicado de explicar

```
$cantidad_orden = $_GET['cantidad_orden'];
$total_piezas = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(`id_caja`) FROM `relacion_modelo_caja` WHERE `id_modelo`= '$id_modelo'")->fetch_row();
if ($total_piezas[0] != 0) {
    //nuevo código
    $cantidad_tickets_get = $_GET['cantidad_orden'];
    $cantidad_tickets_impresos = ($cantidad_tickets_get * $total_piezas[0]);
    ///
    $division = ($cantidad_tickets_impresos / $total_piezas[0]);
    $multiplo_division = ($cantidad_tickets_impresos / $division);
    $cantidad_tickets = $cantidad_tickets_impresos;
} else {
    $multiplo_division = 1;
    $cantidad_tickets = $_GET['cantidad_orden'];
}


$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', array(235, 193)); //vertical horizontal
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, 15);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 5);

$contador = 0;
$contador_ticket_pieza = 0;
while ($cantidad_tickets > $contador) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $multiplo_division; $i++) { //
        if ($i == 0) {
            $numero_pieza = 1;
        } else {
            $numero_pieza = ($i + 1);
        }
        while ($cantidad_tickets > $contador) {
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 13);
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 1);
            $pdf->MultiCell(110, 6, utf8_decode("$descripcion"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->Cell(250, 20, utf8_decode("Modelo"), 0, 0, 'C');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 27);
            $pdf->Cell(-250, 35, utf8_decode("$modelo"), 0, 0, 'C');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 30);
            $pdf->MultiCell(110, 6, utf8_decode("Características:"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
            $pdf->SetXY(165, 35.5);
            $pdf->MultiCell(100, 6, utf8_decode("HECHO"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetXY(169.5, 39.5);
            $pdf->MultiCell(100, 6, utf8_decode("EN"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetXY(165, 43.5);
            $pdf->MultiCell(100, 6, utf8_decode("MÉXICO"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 40); //
            $pdf->Multicell(80, 5, utf8_decode("$prueba_texto_caracteristicas"), 0, 'L'); 
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
            $pdf->Cell(190, 10, utf8_decode("Peso Neto: "), 0, 0, 'C');
            $pdf->Cell(-130, 10, utf8_decode("$peso_kilos"), 0, 0, 'C');
            $pdf->Cell(190, 10, utf8_decode("Kgs."), 0, 0, 'C');
 
            $contador++;
            if ($multiplo_division == 1) {
            } else {
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
                $pdf->SetXY(105, 30);
                $pdf->MultiCell(100, 8, utf8_decode("PIEZA $numero_pieza DE $multiplo_division"), 0, 'C');

            }
            break;
        }

        while ($cantidad_tickets > $contador) {
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 13);
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 70);
            $pdf->MultiCell(110, 6, utf8_decode("$descripcion"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 81);
            $pdf->MultiCell(110, 6, utf8_decode("Modelo"), 0, 'C');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 27);
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 88.5);
            $pdf->MultiCell(110, 6, utf8_decode("$modelo"), 0, 'C');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 100);
            $pdf->MultiCell(110, 6, utf8_decode("Características:"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
            $pdf->SetXY(165, 105);
            $pdf->MultiCell(100, 6, utf8_decode("HECHO"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetXY(169.5, 109);
            $pdf->MultiCell(100, 6, utf8_decode("EN"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetXY(165, 113.5);
            $pdf->MultiCell(100, 6, utf8_decode("MÉXICO"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 108);
            $pdf->Multicell(80, 5, utf8_decode("$prueba_texto_caracteristicas"), 0, 'L'); 
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
            $pdf->SetXY(93, 120);
            $pdf->Multicell(80, 5, utf8_decode("Peso Neto: "), 0, 'L');
            $pdf->SetXY(134, 120);
            $pdf->Multicell(80, 5, utf8_decode("$peso_kilos"), 0, 'L'); 
            $pdf->SetXY(160, 120);
            $pdf->Multicell(80, 5, utf8_decode("Kgs."), 0, 'L');
            if ($multiplo_division == 1) {
            } else {
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
                $pdf->SetXY(138, 98);
                $pdf->Multicell(80, 5, utf8_decode("PIEZA $numero_pieza DE $multiplo_division"), 0, 'L'); //

            }
            $contador++;
            break;
        }

        while ($cantidad_tickets > $contador) {
            $pdf->Ln();
            $pdf->Ln();
            // $pdf->Image("$logo_actual", '0', '147', '83', '65', 'png'); logo de epcom
            $pdf->Image('tickets/fondo_blanco_improvisado.png', '80', '155', '110', '70', 'png'); /// Imagen de fondo
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 13);
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 135);
            $pdf->MultiCell(110, 6, utf8_decode("$descripcion"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 145);
            $pdf->MultiCell(110, 6, utf8_decode("Modelo"), 0, 'C');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 27);
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 152.5);
            $pdf->MultiCell(110, 6, utf8_decode("$modelo"), 0, 'C');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 160);
            $pdf->MultiCell(110, 6, utf8_decode("Características:"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
            $pdf->SetXY(165, 168);
            $pdf->MultiCell(100, 6, utf8_decode("HECHO"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetXY(169.5, 172);
            $pdf->MultiCell(100, 6, utf8_decode("EN"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetXY(165, 176.5);
            $pdf->MultiCell(100, 6, utf8_decode("MÉXICO"), 0, 'LR');
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
            $pdf->SetXY(80, 168.5);
            $pdf->Multicell(80, 5, utf8_decode("$prueba_texto_caracteristicas"), 0, 'L'); //Reemplazar la variable cuando existan datos guardados $caracteristicas_modelo[0] 
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
            $pdf->SetXY(93, 185);
            $pdf->Multicell(80, 5, utf8_decode("Peso Neto: "), 0, 'L');
            $pdf->SetXY(134, 185);
            $pdf->Multicell(80, 5, utf8_decode("$peso_kilos"), 0, 'L');
            $pdf->SetXY(160, 185);
            $pdf->Multicell(80, 5, utf8_decode("Kgs."), 0, 'L');
            if ($multiplo_division == 1) {
            } else {
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
                $pdf->SetXY(138, 162);
                $pdf->Multicell(80, 5, utf8_decode("PIEZA $numero_pieza DE $multiplo_division"), 0, 'L'); //

            }
            $contador++;
            if ($cantidad_tickets > $contador) {
                $pdf->AddPage();
                // $pdf->AddPage('P', 'Letter', 0);//set auto oage
                $pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, 15);
                $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 5);
                // $pdf->Image('tickets/fondo.jpg', '0', '0', '200', '300', 'JPG');
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: no es mas facil crear un html con los datos y ubicar en cada variable el Numero actua +0 o +1 o +2 o +3, y al final hacer el $count+=4; respectivo???

Comment: otra cosa a esa etiqueta le falta el codigo de barra registrado ....

Comment: pero al hacer un count pues tecnicamente no me sirve ya que mis whiles ya funcionan para saber cuando parar de "imprimir" los tickets pero el problema es más bien por ejemplo si son 100 tickets y 4 cajas pues quiero 25 tickets que digan pieza 1 de 4 y así sucesivamente no sé si me explico, sé que debe ser algo así pero no se me ocurre una solución

Comment: a ver si te piden 25 cajas y cada cajas tienen 4 unidades perfecto ya sabes que son 100 ticket pero eso no te soluciona el conteo de unidades por cajas y para saber eso tienes que llevar un conteo de esas unidades por cajas... que se resetea cada 4 unidades... y ese controlador es dinámico ya que dependerá del producto y su formato de 1:4, 1:6, 1:8, 1:10 etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la cuestión es que te estás enfrentando al [Problema de Paginación](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+paginacion).
Observa el siguiente ejemplo genérico:

```
Items  | 1, 2, 3, 4 | 5, 6, 7, 8 | 9, 10 |
-------+------------+------------+-------+
Ticket |     1      |      2     |   3   |

Cantidad de items: 10
Cantidad de items por ticket = 4
Entonces, cantidad de tickets = ceil(10 // 4) = 3
```

El siguiente código, también genérico, puede calcular: todos los items que están en determinado ticket, en qué ticket está determinado ítem y también imprimir todos los tickets con sus items.

```php
<?php
class Tickets {
    function __construct($cantItems, $divisiones) {
        $this->cant_items = $cantItems;
        $this->cant_x_tck = $divisiones;
        $this->numTickets = intval(ceil($cantItems / $divisiones));
        // ** Ver nota al final **
        // $this->numTickets = $divisiones;
        // $this->cant_x_tck = intval(ceil($cantItems / $divisiones));
    }
    
    function get_itemsXTicket($num_ticket, $item=true) {
        if(($num_ticket > 0) and ($num_ticket <= $this->numTickets)) {
            $inicio = (($num_ticket - 1) * $this->cant_x_tck) + 1;
            $final = $inicio + $this->cant_x_tck - 1;
            $sobrante = ($final <= $this->cant_items) ? 0 : $final - $this->cant_items;
            $final_neto = $final - $sobrante;
            if(!$item) {
                $inicio = 1;
                $final_neto = $this->cant_x_tck - $sobrante;
            }
            return implode(", ", range($inicio, $final_neto));
        } // else // num_ticket no puede ser 0 ni mayor que la cantidad de tickets
        return False;
    }
    
    function get_ticket($num_item) { // En qué ticket está el item # num_item
        if(($num_item > 0) and ($num_item <= $this->cant_items)) {
            return ceil($num_item / $this->cant_x_tck);
        } // else // num_item no puede ser 0 o mayor que el numero de items.
        return False;
    }
    
    function print_all_tickets($item=true) {
        foreach(range(1, $this->numTickets) as $nTck) {
            echo "Ticket $nTck -> " . $this->get_itemsXTicket($nTck, $item) . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora haciendo unas pruebas:

```php
> $obj = new Tickets(10, 4); // 10 items, 4 items por ticket
> echo $obj->get_itemsXTicket(2); // Traer los items del ticket 2
5, 6, 7, 8
> echo $obj->get_ticket(6); // ¿En qué ticket está el item 6?
2
> $obj->print_all_tickets(); // Imprimir todos los tickets
Ticket 1 -> 1, 2, 3, 4
Ticket 2 -> 5, 6, 7, 8
Ticket 3 -> 9, 10
> $obj->print_all_tickets(false); // Todos los tickets sin num de item.
Ticket 1 -> 1, 2, 3, 4
Ticket 2 -> 1, 2, 3, 4
Ticket 3 -> 1, 2
```

Preguntarás ¿y las dos líneas comentadas en el constructor de la clase?. Es en caso que necesites emplear la lógica al contrario: En vez de darle el num de elementos que tiene un ticket, ahora `divisiones` será el num de tickets y el programa calcula cuántos items debe tener cada ticket.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo con este ejemplo pude resolver mi problema te lo agradezco